# textarea inside div

Tags: css, html, textarea

I think i'm doing something wrong here, I expect the textarea to be 10px smaller than the parent div on every side, but it's not like that, it's too small:

```
<html>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width:50%; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <textarea style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; border: 1px solid #FF0000; resize:none;"></textarea>
  </div>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2a7LR/1/

why does this happen ? and how can i make it so it fits 10 px smaller in each side from the parent div ?

It appears correctly only in chrome/safari, but wrong in every other browser ( firefox, opera, IE8 )

Comment: do you need exactly 10px or can you use % width/height for the textbox?

Comment: even with percentages it doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/2a7LR/6/

Answer (score 10):

http://jsfiddle.net/2a7LR/5/ Adjusted some CSS for you. Basically used `width: 100%; height: 100%`, moved the `10px` to the container's `padding` property, then added `box-sizing` to the textarea to make the size take the border into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width:50%; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <textarea style="position: relative; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width:90%; height: 90%"></textarea>
</div>
</html>​
```

This should work for you. the text area can be relative inside a absolute div. you just need to position it with margins and not with top and left.

Cheers, Fede

EDIT: and also noticed you haven't set any width and height in the text area so it's not suppost to know the size of it - it just puts the default .

Answer (score -2):

http://jsfiddle.net/EzJ8G/1/
Replace the style in textarea and add padding:10px;